# MS Excel: Return all characters before first number

Tags: excel, split, formula

I MS Excel 2013 I have a column that lists postal code information. It contains a 4 digit postal code followed by a city name, but in some fields the postal code is preceeded by a town name, like this:

> 7100 Vejle
>
> 8600 Silkeborg
>
> Grauballe 8600 Silkeborg

I want to split this data into three columns: town name (empty in most instances), postal code and city name, so I need to a formula that returns all characters before the first number, but I can't figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use "Text to Columns", using Space as the delimiter. This will split your data into two or three columns depending on whether there is a town name present or not. You can then use a formula on this data to sort the data into correct columns.

Assuming that once you have done *Text to Columns* your data is present in Columns B, C and sometimes D, entering this formula adjacent to your data, say in F2, and dragging across three columns, and downward for all your rows, will sort your data correctly:

```
=IF($D2="", IF(A2="", "", A2), B2)
```

Comment: Nice use of relative addressing (although perhaps you should say it depends on having blank cells in column A)